# Why can't my HTML dropdown find my function?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

So I am trying to make a simple dropdown menu that when a value is clicked a function is run, but I'm having some issues accessing the function.

When I run [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnh7qao/4/) (code below), I get a console message of 'made it'.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dropdown">
<select>
    <option>Near</option>
    <option onclick="console.log('made it');">Far</option>
    <option>Very Far</option>
    <option>Distant</option>
</select>
</div>
```

But if I try to move the message into a function [like in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnh7qao/3/) (code below), I get an error saying the function `test` is not defined.

**HTML**

```
<div id="dropdown">
<select>
    <option>Near</option>
    <option onclick="test();">Far</option>
    <option>Very Far</option>
    <option>Distant</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var test = function () {
    console.log("Made it");
};
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Shouldn't my HTML `onclick` be able to find the `test()` function?

Comment: actually the code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/wdoL3auq/v) with a correct setup.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kgnh7qao/5/ http://doc.jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Mikey [where the hell did your heard that?](http://jsfiddle.net/ypye1anx/)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Hmmmm, I must have wrongly remembered. I have read an article a while ago that looked for a cleaner way. Sorry... http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2013/01/26/console-log-with-jsfiddle/

Comment: @Mikey Ok, I mean, `console` is a native object so there is nothing to do with jsfiddle itself.